# Эвристический поиск в лабиринте

Tags: prolog

Лабиринт представляет собой систему комнат,соединенных между собой переходами.В лабиринте имеется вход и выход,а также комната с золотым кладом.Кроме того,имеются комнаты,запрещенные для посещений:комната монстров и комната разбойников.

1. Найди путь в лабиринте от входа до входа,не посещая дважды одной и той же комнаты.
2. Найти путь с посещением золотой комнаты.
3. Найти путь,избегающий запрещенных к посещению комнат.
4. Подсчет количество пройденных комнат.

Comment: @BelashovaAV, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

описываешь граф:

```
edge(in, out).
edge(in, gold).
edge(in, monster).
edge(in, robber).

edge(gold, out).
edge(gold, monster).
edge(gold, robber).

edge(monster, out).
edge(monster, gold).
edge(monster, robber).

edge(robber, out).
edge(robber, gold).
edge(robber, monster).
```

(описать можно по-разному, у тебя не сказано в задаче между какими комнатами есть переходы. Запускаешь любой алгоритм поиска (хоть в ширину, хоть в глубину).
Код взят из статьи [решение логических задач](http://pro-prof.com/archives/1299), пояснения к коду и алгоритмы обхода можно там найти.

Answer (score 0):

Вся эта задача упирается в написания алгоритма обхождения препятствий.

Предполагаю что подойдет, волновой, или любая его модификация.

Comment: Кто-нибудь знает готовый код этой программы на прологе?правда,очень надо!

Comment: Готовый код? Как был ответ выше, это не по правилам форума.
В интернете куча объяснений данного алгоритма.
Он не такой уж и сложный.

Comment: извините не увидела.